# Multiple insert speed up

Tags: java, mysql

i'm parsing large log files (5+GB) and extracting ad-hoc placed profiling lines (call name and execution time). I want to insert those lines into a MySql db.

My question is: should I execute the insert statement every time I get the line while parsing or there's some best practice to speed up everything?

Comment: make sure you do **not** have unique keys on that table, or your insert will get really slow, even using `load data infile`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If there is any way that you could do a bulk insert, that would help a lot (or at least send your data to the database in batches, instead of making separate calls each time).

**Edit**

LOAD DATA INFILE sounds even faster ;o)

https://web.archive.org/web/20150413042140/http://jeffrick.com/2010/03/23/bulk-insert-into-a-mysql-database

Comment: +1 for the `LOAD DATA INFILE` recommend (just have to make sure permissions are set to allow it).

Comment: Implemented: really fast. Thx a lot.

Answer (score 3):

There are better options. 
See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-speed.html

In your case, I think writing the relevant records to a file and then using LOAD DATA INFILE is the best approach.

Comment: @Jon - another favorite is http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html

Answer (score 1):

For small updates, the number of transactions is critical for performance.  SO if you can perform a number of inserts in the same transaction it will go much faster.  I would try 100 inserts per transaction first.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to follow the recommendations in Galz's link ( which is excellent BTW ) then try to open the connection and prepare the statement once, then loop round your log files carrying out the inserts ( using the premared statement ), then finally close the statement and connection once at the end. It's not the fastest way of doing the inserts, but it's the fastest way that sticks to a "normal" JDBC approach.

Answer (score 0):

From java
[JDBC batch insert](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/guide/jdbc/spec2/jdbc2.1.frame6.html)

Example:
You do this with every insert: http://code.google.com/p/hunglish-webapp/source/browse/trunk/src/main/java/hu/mokk/hunglish/lucene/Indexer.java#232

You do this with every batch http://code.google.com/p/hunglish-webapp/source/browse/trunk/src/main/java/hu/mokk/hunglish/lucene/Indexer.java#371

The size of the batch can be determined by the available memory.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from insert speed, the other problem you may run into is memory.  Whatever approach you use, you will still need to consider your memory usage as the records are loaded from the file.  Unless you have a hard requirement on processing speed, then it may be a better to use an approach with a predictable memory foot print.